# T-SQL date difference between multiple rows

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, datetime, datediff

I want the `Id_Pass` where the difference between 2 or more dates is more than 10 days. I've tried datediff but I feel it's getting too complex.

```
+------------+-----------+-------+
|    Date    |  Id_Pass  | Value |
+------------+-----------+-------+
| 2011-03-18 | PASS00004 |    30 |
| 2011-03-19 | PASS00004 |    60 |
| 2012-02-25 | PASS00005 |    30 |
| 2012-04-25 | PASS00005 |    30 |
+------------+-----------+-------+
```

Desired result:

```
+-----------+
|  Id_Pass  |
+-----------+
| PASS00005 |
+-----------+
```

Comment: Why `PASS00004` is your desired result? Explain it.

Comment: For `PASS00004` the difference is only 1 day. According your question, the desired result should be `PASS00005`, because the difference is 2 months. Which one is the desired result?

Comment: `PASS00005` is my desired result, misstyped.

Comment: In this case check Salman A's answer, it should work for you.

Comment: Did it thanks to the rajit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the [`LAG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) window function to find previous date for each row:

```
SELECT Id_Pass
FROM (
    SELECT Id_Pass, Date, LAG(Date) OVER (PARTITION BY Id_Pass ORDER BY Date) AS PrevDate
    FROM yourdata
) AS cte
WHERE Date > DATEADD(DAY, 10, PrevDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use lag() function

```
select * from
(
select *, DATEDIFF(day, LAG(Date,1, Date) OVER (partition by Id_Pass ORDER BY Date)) as daydiff
)A where daydiff>10
```